# jtable title is not shown

Tags: java, jtable

I want to do a JTable with column names, using:

```
JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)
```

to constructs a JTable to display the values in the Vector of Vectors, rowData, with column names, columnNames.

So, I did this:

```
final String[] columnNames = {"NOMBRE", "DÍAS DE LA SEMANA", "HORA DE INICIO", "HORA DE FIN", "TIEMPO MÁXIMO DE USO"};

        rs.last();
        int numRows = rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst(); 

        Object[][] columnData = new String[numRows][5];

        int i = 0;
        while(rs.next()){

            columnData[i][0] = rs.getString(1);
            columnData[i][1] = rs.getString(2);
            columnData[i][2] = rs.getString(3);
            columnData[i][3] = rs.getString(4);
            columnData[i][4] = rs.getString(5);

        }

table = new JTable(columnData, columnNames);
        table.setBounds(300,600,700,150);
```

But I only see the data, why isn't the title shown?

Thank in advance

Comment: Put it in a JScrollPane.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047090/jtable-column-header-not-visible Possibly a duplicate. You need to have JTable on a scrollpane for title to be visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JTable table = new JTable(columnData, columnNames);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
panel.add(scroll);
```